# Multiple localized ASPX layouts/templates without locale-specific URIs

Tags: asp.net, webforms, localization, internationalization, globalization

We have large bodies of structured text (document templates) that we'd like to localize *as part of the application*. This is not content that should be in the database.

To achieve this, the simplest thing we could think of was to use localized ASPX templates that inherit from the same type defined in the same code-behind file.

**However, we'd like to map these templates to the same URI as well**, and select which one to use based on the current culture.

**http://example.com/Foo.aspx > Foo.*$LOCALE*.aspx**

We'd like to do this without redirection, though making the explicit URI available would be NTH.

While some people seem to reinvent template languages and cram their templates in resource files that would be handled by dedicated template engines instead, we'd really like to leverage the ASPX template engine.

Is there any way to do this in a straightforward manner?

---

Edit: Per the comments, here is a sample template to illustrate:

**WebForm1-en.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>WebForm1 - English</title>
<div>Hello!</div>
<div><%: Foo %></div>
```

**WebForm1-fr.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>WebForm1 - Français</title>
<div>Bonjour!</div>
<div><%: Foo %></div>
```

**WebForm1.aspx.cs**

```
namespace WebApplication1 {
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page {
        public int Foo { get; set; }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
            Foo = 42;
        }
    }
}
```

The goal would be to somehow route `/WebForm1.aspx` to either `/WebForm1-en.aspx` or `/WebForm1-fr.aspx` depending on the current locale/culture (without redirection).

`/WebForm1.aspx` may or may not be virtual: indeed it would be ideal if it could be concrete and used as a fallback template.

---

This question is the same as *[Multiple localized aspx layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724865/multiple-localized-aspx-layouts)*, though no answer there provide a hint as to how to achieve this without requiring separate URIs for each locale.

I'm not sure I did the right thing by re-asking the question here in more specific terms -- as it's quite old, I don't think editing it would achieve much. In any case, I'll welcome suggestions for other ways to go about this.

Comment: Could you post a part of what one of your existing templates looks like, what inputs you'd be seeking, and what transformations you'd like to see performed on them?

Comment: Done; not sure the templates are very interesting though. I only just discovered Web Forms' support for standard ASP.NET routing, I suppose this can be used to achieve the necessary wiring, I'm looking into it.

Comment: When I saw the template examples, my first thought was: "Why not also store the localized verbiage in the database?" and then dynamically set the verbiage as appropriate.  However, your question starts with "This is not content that should be in the database" so can we assume there's more to the templates' differences than localized text?  Assuming you've considered this, just out of curiosity: how do you propagate (and translate) changes to all copies of a given template?

Comment: @JimMSDN Thanks for following up. All of our **static** translations (which include strings, stored in `resx` files) are committed in source control. I would imagine this is a pretty standard setup for small-to-mid size applications. We hit the usual problem that some "strings" really are more than simple strings (they are documents with dynamic values). Some solutions include splitting these documents in many strings (we end up with very unhelpful IDs, such as paragraph1, paragraph2, etc) or use a template language inside the resource values. We'd like to use ASPX for these.

Comment: @JimMSDN To answer your question on propagation directly, if we *can* propagate changes automatically, then we're doing it wrong; it should be split into smaller parts or even small strings in `resx` files. Hence, we're only talking about texts that will necessary *require* human intervention (to translate) on every modification. Imagine a text where we reorder/merge/split paragraphs for example -- you'd need a human translator to figure out the changes. The actual common structure is of course extracted in master pages, and will propagate automatically. Our dynamic content is of course in DB.